# Used SequentialFeatureSelector but does not improve the model accuracy

Tags: python, random-forest, feature-selection

I am selecting features for building a churn prediction model. With the RandomForestClassifier, I got an accuracy of 0.9517 and it showed 16 features selected as part of this.

However, if I fit a model using the same list of 16 features with RandomForestClassifier separately, it shows an accuracy score of 0.8714, Why is there a huge difference in accuracy score although I used the same list of features selected by SequentialFeatureSelector?

> [2019-01-28 17:51:16] Features: 16/16 -- score:
>   0.9517879681082387[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    3.6s remaining:    0.0s

```
rand_forest = RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, 
                class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
                max_depth=None, max_features='auto', 
                max_leaf_nodes=None,
                min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1,
                oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
                warm_start=False)

SequentialFeatureSelector(clone_estimator=True, cv=0,
             estimator=rand_forest,
             floating=False, forward=True, k_features=16, n_jobs=1,
             pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', scoring='accuracy', verbose=2)

xtr, xtst, ytr, ytst = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=5, test_size=0.2)

rfst = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)

rfstmodel = rfst.fit(xtr, ytr)

rfstmodel.score(xtst, ytst)

>>> 0.8714975845410629
```

Answer (score 0):

Random Forest Classifiers don't just randomize the features, they also randomize the splits of those features, so even though your features are staying the same, your feature-splits are being randomly generated each time, which can introduce some variance into the model. For a more regularized model with on-average less variance, I recommend a [Gradient Boosted Model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html), or better yet [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn).

> Random Forest adds additional randomness to the model, while growing
>   the trees. Instead of searching for the most important feature while
>   splitting a node, it searches for the best feature among a random
>   subset of features. This results in a wide diversity that generally
>   results in a better model.
>
> Therefore, in Random Forest, only a random subset of the features is
>   taken into consideration by the algorithm for splitting a node. **You
>   can even make trees more random, by additionally using random
>   thresholds for each feature rather than searching for the best
>   possible thresholds** (like a normal decision tree does).

Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-random-forest-algorithm-d457d499ffcd